# what is difference between pchar and pbyte

Tags: delphi, pointer-arithmetic

Why can't I perform this operation:

```
var
  data:pbyte;
  x:int64;
  o:pointer; 
begin
  o:=data+x;
end;
```

Comment: Just a punt, but is a `pchar` 16-bit and a `pbyte` 8-bit, as `char` and `byte` are in C#?

Comment: In D2009 and later, `Char` is 16-bit, yes.  In earlier versions, it is 8-bit.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a 64bit integer (Int64) for pointer arithmetic in a 32bit language? I would suggest using Cardinal instead.

Answer (score 11):

PChar is a pointer to char, but it receives special support from the compiler to allow pointer arithmetic to make C-like string manipulations easier in Delphi.  PByte is just a plain old typed pointer, and does not receive any special attention from the compiler to allow pointer arithmetic.

In Delphi 2009, [a new compiler directive was introduced](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/01/24/38852) ($POINTERMATH ON/OFF) which allows you to add compiler support for pointer arithmetic to your own pointer type declarations.

Comment: Actually, Inc() and Dec() style pointer math has been working for ages (see http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_2224.asp); Delphi 2009 now adds suport for arithmic in the MyPInt[index] style if you enable that directive (see http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html).

Comment: thanks for info ,is ther any chance that i can attain in delphi 7 ? :S

Comment: No, Steve. Delphi 7 was released about a decade ago, and there have been five subsequent releases. There will be no further releases of that version. What you have now is all you're ever going to have, unless you upgrade to a new version.

Comment: Actually, PByte behave much like PChar on new Delphi with pointer math. "The fundamental type PByte represents a pointer to any byte data that is not character data. This type is declared with the {$POINTERMATH ON} compiler directive".

Comment: @Alexander: Sure, in Delphi 2009 or later.  I haven't used that version.  The OP has Delphi 7, so PByte doesn't have benefit of that Delphi 2009 compiler directive.

Comment: I don't have an older version of Delphi to test it... But I guess instead of "P := P + X", it could be done "P := @P[X]" if pointermath isn't enabled for PByte. (Or any pointer to a 8-bits sized element)

Comment: @Ken: Or just use Inc(P,X) as noted by Jeroen above.

Answer (score 3):

```
pbyte = ^byte;
pchar = ^char;
```

In old Delphi versions (prior to D2009), `SizeOf(char)`=`SizeOf(byte)`, i.e., 8-bit.
In D2009 and later, `char` is 16-bit whereas `byte` remains 8-bit, so that:

```
SizeOf(byte)=1
SizeOf(char)=2
```

To allow modifying pointers by e.g. adding values etc., you can use `$POINTERMATH ON` (available in D2009 and later, see [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirspointermath_xml.html)). The alternative is to follow the pattern:

```
NewPointer:= Pointer(Integer(OldPointer)+IntegerValue)
```

Edit1 -- Note that (as pointed out in comments to another answer), also `inc()` and `dec()` work with typed pointers; they will increment/decrement a PMyType by SizeOf(TMyType).

Edit2 -- For future-proofing your code, you should consider that SizeOf(Pointer) will probably change in future 64-bit Delphi versions, so that the relationship `SizeOf(Integer)=SizeOf(Pointer)` will no longer hold. To circumvent this, recent Delphi versions define the types `NativeInt` and `NativeUInt`, which are integers that have the same size as a `pointer`.

Comment: Define and start using a separate type to cast pointers to integers. Soon, a pointer won't fit in an integer anymore. (Due to 64-bit).

Comment: @Marco - Yes, good point. There are NativeInt/NativeUInt in recent Delphi versions. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Note that Inc and Dec only work on typed pointers, e.g. PByte, not on untyped (pointer). You may need to use something like  `type NativeInt : LongInt;...o := Pointer(NativeInt(Data) + x * SizeOf(byte));`

Comment: @Gerry - Yes. I do actually say _typed_ _pointers_. And yes, when you are doing the pointer math manually, of course you need to make sure you are adding the correct offsets.

Comment: I intended my comment as a general *pointer* for people less familiar with Pascal. Mind upu it was late at night where I live